# How python records information about all method calls on a class object(Includes built-in methods eg.__getattr__)?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-decorators, metaclass

A class creates an object that prints out the method name when the object calls a function and prints out the runtime when the function is finished.
For example:

```py
class A(): # We can inherit any class we want
    age = 12
    price = 20
    def say(self):
        print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.say()
    a.age = 15

# The following should occur：
# 'A.some_method' is called                 # Print the name of method
# 'Hello World'                             # Function execution
# 'A.some_method' finished in 0.0000001ms.  # Print function execution time
# a.age = 15                                # Calls and assignments to general properties do not print any information
```

The same effect can be achieved when we call some built-in methods, such as `__getattr__`,`__getattribute__`,`__dict__`.

What should I do?Please help me,thanks everyone.

Comment: `__dict__` isn't a method.

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry,```__dict__``` is an attribute.

Comment: @zanseb So great,thank you.It successfully solved my problem.